# Where should I tally views for an article in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am having serious database issues with a server. The server receives so many connections that since the table was MyISAM it was being blocked whenever I updated a column. One of the columns was `view_count`. Every time an article is visited the column for that article is incremented by 1. So as you can imagine, if a bunch of people visited the site at once then it would take a while for the last person's page to load. My question is:

Would it be wise to split the count for the views into their own table? Or should I convert to InnoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new table with a primary key, foreign key to your existing table and timestamp. I wouldn't store the view_count as either you're going to lock the table for update or have issues when you're getting the previous record's count to increment. When you want to count the hits, just do a sum. This way you have high transactional throughput.

Comment: InnoDB is the one that does suppor referential integrity, in contrast to MyISAM.

Comment: Would the table structure of this new table be MyISAM?

Comment: Ok so whenever I call an insert on this (MyISAM?) table it wouldn't lock it since it is only appending it to the bottom of the list right? Wouldn't the size of this grow extra large?

Comment: Yes it will get "large" but transactionally it's quick. The alternative is locking a table every time a user views an article. I don't know how much traffic you're expecting but with the index that the foreign key gives you, it should be quick enough to look up the number of viewers for a given article well into the millions.

Comment: To put it into context, one million mysql ints (32 bit) take 3mb of storage. Two keys and a date and a few millions rows isn't going to  use too much space.